# Deploy Laravel Project on a Server without Root Permissions

Tags: laravel, deployment, server

I am in a situation that I have built a Laravel Project on my Local Machine, but on the Production Server where I want to Deploy it I do not have Root Permissions thus I cannot install Composer... Is it still possible to Deploy Laravel Project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on how/what you mean by deploy. If you don't have composer on the production server, you just have to make sure the vendor directory is uploaded to the production server.

Not sure what restrictions you have, but have you thought about installing composer locally under your account on the server?

see https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#locally

Comment: Hmmm.. will try the local installation... If it will be installed without Root Access and will be executable I guess it will solve my problem. Thank you, I will notify.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to deploy laravel without accessing any terminal or root access, you just need to compiled all the things your application needs before deploying to that hosting, I do this everytime to my node_modules when I get lazy accessing my SSH, I compiles everything in my Local Machine then uploads it to the production server.

Comment: but what regarding the artisan clear:cache command etc... ? Aren't these necesary?

Comment: Yes! indeed specially if your project had a lot of routes, clear cache etc. you need to run those commands, to speed up. ->  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/deployment#optimizing-configuration-loading, but regarding the project size, you can deploy laravel without running these commands.